# Apache Cordova Error when publishing app in the google play stores

Tags: android, apache, cordova, android-securityexception, android-security

I had searched every where i havnt got any solution regarding this error and i am not able to understand why i am getting this error i had no dangerous products in it please anybody guide are solution for that please this is the main activity did i need to make any changes in it?

```
MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    View content;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private boolean home = true;
    TextView tv_name,tv_phone;
    Session session;
    String seson_name,seson_phone;
    SharedPreferences.Editor logineditor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Session class instance
        session = new Session(getApplicationContext());
        // get user data from session
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
        // name
        seson_name = user.get(Session.KEY_UNAME);
        seson_phone= user.get(Session.KEY_PHONE);

        tv_name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.hd_name);
        tv_phone=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.hd_phone);

        tv_name.setText(seson_name);
        tv_phone.setText(seson_phone);
```

[this the project structure please check it how can add the cordova here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyOM4.png)
[Please check this to know the error from the google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpPFr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Update your cordova version

```
npm install -g cordova
cd my_project
cordova platform update android
```